# How to get unexported types with reflect?

Tags: go

Imagine someone has initialized a [rpc client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/rpc#Client) with `client, _ := rpc.Dial('tcp', 'example.com:port')` and provides you only the rpc client instance. For some reason, you'd like to get the address `example.com` from the client instance. However, as the client type is highly abstracted, you cannot directly get the `net.Conn` instance which serves a `RemoteAddr()` method. In this case, the [reflect package](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) might be helpful.

Lets start with the following attempt:

```
func getRemoteAddr(client *rpc.Client) net.Addr {
  codec := reflect.Indirect(rpclient).FieldByName("codec")
  connV := codec.FieldByName("rwc")
  conn := connV.Interface().(net.Conn)
  return conn.RemoteAddr()
}
```

However, an error jumped out immediately from the second line:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on interface Value
```

This is reasonable as `codec` is declared as type `ClientCodec` which is just an interface with four methods' signatures. However, from the code, we know that the detailed type of `codec` might be the unexported struct `gobClientCodec`. Unfortunately, the Go compiler is not smart enough to trace down that deep and figure out the actual type. Therefore, is there a way with the reflect package to tell the compiler that I'm confident with the type of `codec` to be the unexported `gobClientCodec`? If this is not possible, I'll probably have to calculate the address offset and play with the unsafe pointers, which is the last choice.

P.S. The default `Type()` method from the reflect method won't work as `codec` is declared as `ClientCodec` and initialized by passing the address of a `gobClientCodec` struct in the `NewClient` method as follow:

```
func NewClient(conn io.ReadWriteCloser) *Client {
    encBuf := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
    client := &gobClientCodec{conn, gob.NewDecoder(conn), gob.NewEncoder(encBuf), encBuf}
    return NewClientWithCodec(client)
}
```

Also, `reflect.TypeOf(rpc.gobClientCodec)` won't work as well as the compiler refuses unexported type usages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.Elem()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.17.6#Value.Elem) to get the value contained in the interface.

> Elem returns the value that **the interface v contains** or that the
> pointer v points to. It panics if v's Kind is not Interface or Ptr. It
> returns the zero Value if v is nil.

And for your specific use-case you'll also need to use the [`unsafe`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe@go1.17.6) package to get access to unexported fields. Make sure to read unsafe's documentation before you use it.

```golang
func getRemoteAddr(client *rpc.Client) net.Addr {
  rv := reflect.ValueOf(client)
  rv = rv.Elem()               // deref *rpc.Client
  rv = rv.FieldByName("codec") // get "codec" field from rpc.Client
  rv = rv.Elem()               // get the value that ClientCodec contains
  rv = rv.Elem()               // deref *gobClientCodec
  rv = rv.FieldByName("rwc")   // get "rwc" field from gobClientCodec

  conn := *(*net.Conn)(unsafe.Pointer(rv.UnsafeAddr()))
  return conn.RemoteAddr()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/cHHdwQJ7DE7

Comment: This works, much appreciation. However, it's kind of interested that if I replace the two `rv.Elem()` with `reflect.Indirect(rv).Elem()` the code doesn't work anymore. Weird.

Comment: @TJM `reflect.Indirect` calls `.Elem()` if `rv` is of kind `Ptr`. So if `rv.Kind()` is `Ptr` then doing `reflect.Inderect(rv).Elem()` is the same as `rv.Elem().Elem()`. This will either work or panic depending on what value `rv` represents.